# weird regex behavior in the tokenization

Tags: c#, regex, tokenize

I am using the following regex to tokenize:

```
reg = new Regex("([ \\t{}%$^&*():;_–`,\\-\\d!\"?\n])");
```

The regex is supposed to filter out everything later, however the input string format that i am having problem with is in the following form:

```
; "string1"; "string2"; "string...n";
```

the result of the string: `; "social life"; "city life"; "real life"` as I know should be like the following:

```
; White " social White life " ; White " city White life " ;  White " real White life "
```

However there is a problem such that, I get the output in the following form

```
; empty White empty " social White life " empty ; empty White empty " city White life " empty ; empty White empty " real White life " empty
```

White: means White-Space,
empty: means empty entry in the split array.

My code for split is as following:

```
string[] ret = reg.Split(input);
 for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ret[i] == "")
                Response.Write("empty<br>");
            else
                if (ret[i] == " ")
                    Response.Write("White<br>");
                else
                    Response.Write(ret[i] + "<br>");
        }
```

Why I get these empty entries ? and especially when there is `;` followed by space followed by `"` then the result looks like the following:

```
; empty White empty "
```

can I get explanation of why the command adds empty entries ? and how to remove them without any additional O(n) complexity or using another data structure as `ret`

Comment: To simplify this a bit, are you just trying to get the sentences between the quotation marks (then split out the individual words)?

Comment: I need everything tokenized and then I will get rid of all symbols except " and ;

Comment: [`Regex.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d\(v=vs.110\).aspx) will always add an empty element in the following cases:

 - *If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array.*
 - *If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array. For example, splitting a string on a single hyphen causes the returned array to include an empty string in the position where two adjacent hyphens are found, as the following code shows.*

Comment: I do not understand what is the criterion to match an empty string. What do you mean by *empty entry in the split array*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, splitting at regex matches is almost always not the best idea. You'll get much better results through plain matching.

And regexes are very well suited for tokenization purposes, as they let you implement a state machine really easily, just take a look at that:

```
\G(?:
  (?<string> "(?>[^"\\]+|\\.)*" )
| (?<separator> ; )
| (?<whitespace> \s+ )
| (?<invalid> . )
)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV2tB2/2) - use this with `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` of course.

Here, each match will have the following properties:

- It will start at the end of the previous match, so there will be no unmatched text
- It will contain *exactly* one matching group
- The name of the group tells you the token type
- You can ignore the `whitespace` group, and you should raise an error if you ever encounter a matching `invalid` group.

The `string` group will match an entire quoted string, it can handle escapes such as `\"` inside the string.

The `invalid` group should always be last in the pattern. You may add rules for other other types.

Some example code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"
    \G(?:
      (?<string> ""(?>[^""\\]+|\\.)*"" )
    | (?<separator> ; )
    | (?<whitespace> \s+ )
    | (?<invalid> . )
    )
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

var input = "; \"social life\"; \"city life\"; \"real life\"";

var groupNames = regex.GetGroupNames().Skip(1).ToList();

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    var groupName = groupNames.Single(name => match.Groups[name].Success);
    var group = match.Groups[groupName];

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", groupName, group.Value);
}
```

This produces the following:

```
separator: ;
whitespace:
string: "social life"
separator: ;
whitespace:
string: "city life"
separator: ;
whitespace:
string: "real life"
```

See how much easier it is to deal with these results rather than using split?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer